# Python selenium can't extract text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape the text from a list, this is the URL:

https://www.eneba.com/es/lego-dimensions-starter-pack-playstation-4

This is my code:

1º I find de list (ul)

2º for each li in ul print the text

```
ul = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[2]/following-sibling::ul') 

li = ul.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
#print(li.text)

for element in li:
    print(element.text)
```

This code returns blank spaces instead of text, what am I doing wrong ?

There some answers of people that  say things without checking anything.
1º The xpath is definetly there, check it
2º There are 29 H2 in the html of the page, not just one

I received a negative vote from people who say the 1º thing the think without even checking anything.
What I want to extract is this text:

> • Rompecabezas - resolver varios acertijos es una de las mecánicas centrales del juego;
> • Para todos los públicos – El juego es apropiado para jugadores de todas las edades;
> • Arcade - los jugadores deben terminar con éxito los niveles que aumentan en dificultad a medida que avanzan en el juego;
> • Acción - este título incluye desafíos que deben superarse utilizando habilidades como precisión, tiempo de respuesta rápido, etc.;
> • Superhéroes - Los jugadores entran en un mundo peligroso, donde los únicos capaces de detener el crimen son los héroes bendecidos con poderes únicos;
> • Un jugador - el juego presenta una campaña en solitario con una historia;
> • Multijugador local - esta función permite que varias personas participen en los mismos partidos, ya sea a través de la pantalla dividida o la misma conexión de red.

Comment: Which text do you want to get? Game titles?

Comment: What do you want to extract from url?? please add that in post with output

Comment: We are seeing a different page than you. I just noticed, it has the message 'Aún no está disponible en tu región.' for me -- I'm not fluent but I assume that means it's not available in the US. So the majority of users here cannot see your content.

Comment: Ok, now your question looks much better.

Comment: Can you also show on a screenshot the text you are looking for? I think it is not visible in my region.

Comment: The text may be different depending on location, but locators will be the same with a high probability.

Comment: @vitaliis I don't see how the locators would be the same? At least for me I can't even assess the locators, I found just one `h2` element when @V-cash says there should be 29!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1** I've managed to get the data from my region, but I had to spend some time on selecting Spain from the list of countries.
Please note that I avoided using xpath locators as they would be too long.
All explanations are in the comments to the code.

**2** To get a text from an element .text is usually used, but for this case is does not work. So `get_attribute("innerHTML")` is what you really need.

I left all waits that I used. YOu can debug by yourself and remove ones that are not necessary.

**Solution:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.eneba.com/es/lego-dimensions-starter-pack-playstation-4')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "._1FArM6>.qGNWom.qGNWom"))).click()  # accept cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".EcNujK._2afX4x._1OhNBA"))).click()  # click region button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#region .css-1hwfws3"))).click()  # change region

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#region .react-select__input>input")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#region .react-select__input>input").send_keys("spa")  # input country name
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#react-select-2-option-5").click()  # select found country
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._3Fpvn5>button[type='submit']").click()  # submit country
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[itemprop=description]>ul>li")))  # wait for all li elements
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[itemprop=description]>ul>li")
for card in cards:
    print(card.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

**Result:**

```
• Rompecabezas - resolver varios acertijos es una de las mecánicas centrales del juego;
• Para todos los públicos – El juego es apropiado para jugadores de todas las edades;
• Arcade - los jugadores deben terminar con éxito los niveles que aumentan en dificultad a medida que avanzan en el juego;
• Acción - este título incluye desafíos que deben superarse utilizando habilidades como precisión, tiempo de respuesta rápido, etc.;
• Superhéroes - Los jugadores entran en un mundo peligroso, donde los únicos capaces de detener el crimen son los héroes bendecidos con poderes únicos;
• Un jugador - el juego presenta una campaña en solitario con una historia;
• Multijugador local - esta función permite que varias personas participen en los mismos partidos, ya sea a través de la pantalla dividida o la misma conexión de red.
```

Comment: Thank you, I used .get_attirbute("innerHTML") instead of .text and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are no elements located by the `xpath` you defined `'//h2[2]/following-sibling::ul`.
This is why `ul` is actually a `null` and `li` is an empty list.

Comment: I thought this too, but why wouldn't it fail with an `ElementNotFoundException` on the first line? But the xpath is definitely wrong, there is only one `h2` tag on the page so `h2[2]` couldn't possibly be right

Comment: Ha. Same here, if it was Java or JavaScript I would know how it should behave

Comment: No, if you inspect and search that xpath with Control+F you'll find it.  It's there.
How did you search it ??
There are 29 H2 in the html code.

Comment: @Vcash I think that your question is not correctly formulated. First, you should specify which elements you are looking for, second you should add html code to it. Some contents of the site is blocked in some countries. For example I see messages like this: "Aún no está disponible en tu región."

Comment: @V-cash I'm sorry, I think I know why this has happened -- we aren't seeing the same page as you. I didn't look too closely before, just searched in the console, but going back to the page I noticed it says "Aún no está disponible en tu región."

Comment: Actually I understood how the problem can be solved. I selected Spain from the list of regions. It made answering this question much more difficult. But it was interesting for me.

Comment: No worries, I didn't know that the site filter by region, and the next time I'll formulate the question better. Thank you all.